# Saving default fields in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model `User` in my Django application:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True)
   username = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
   job = models.ManyToManyField(Job, blank=True, related_name="users", default = JobDefault)
```

which has a field where `JobDefault()` returns a string.

```
def JobDefault():
    return "Artist"

class Job(models.Model):
    job = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, default = JobDefault())
    def __str__(self):
       return self.job
```

So there's a `m2m` field involving `User` and `Job` but I want to set a default "Artist"(which is what `JobDefault()` returns) as the job if a user does not specify a job. Django seems to have a bug which prevents the setting of initial values of the model every time an instance is created.

I tried implementing this by overriding the save method of `User`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.job.all():
        self.job.add(JobDefault())
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but returns an error when I try saving a User object:

```
raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
     ValueError: "<User: hello@gmail.com>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many 
      relationship can be used
```

I also tried using `Postsave`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='SetDefaultName')
def SetDefaultName(self, **kwargs):
    User = kwargs['instance']
    if not User.job.all(): 
        User.job.add(JobDefault)
        User.save()
```

but returns this error when I try to run any `manage.py` command:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='SetDefaultName')
      NameError: name 'User' is not defined
```

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks.

#EDIT 1
Okay so I tried:

```
 def SetDefaultName(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
 if created:
    instance.job.add(JobDefault())
    print("Job been added!")
post_save.connect(SetDefaultName, sender=User)
```

but I get an error:
 `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Artist'.`

Comment: import the `User` model before using it in the signal...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The signal is already in the `User` model. Is it supposed to be outside it?

Comment: Yes the signal is supposed to be outside the model (For some reason people tend do that, regardless this is a bad practice). Best is to write them in a file `signals.py` and import this in the `ready` method of the application's configuration class. Check this [blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) on Simple Is Better Than Complex if you need some reference.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat see post for edit.

Comment: `JobDefault()` returns a string `"Artist"` you need to pass a `Job` instance to the method `instance.job.add(instance_of_a_job_here)`...